# My C++ program doesn't stop when it's supposed to

Tags: c++

I'm trying to learn C++, but every time I try to run my program it closes itself before you see what it has to show, even ignoring my `cin <<` statements.

As you can see, someone told me to fix it using `<cstdio>`, but I don't understand what's happening.

When I run this it stops at the `cout <<` statement at the end, but if I remove one of the two functions at the end (the `cin.get()` or the `getchar()`) it just continues past the first `cin >>` statement, ignoring the other function that in theory should stop the program.

So, I want to know why is this happening, and how can I prevent it without using `<cstdio>` (if possible).

I want to thank everyone who reads this and apologise for my bad English; I'm still learning the language.

I'm using wxDev-C++, if it helps.

Example code below:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
    
using namespace std;
    
int main () {
  //cin.get();
  float n1, iva = 0.21;
  cout << "ingrese un numero"; 
  cin >> n1;
  float n2 = n1 + n1 * iva;
  cout << "este es su numero despues del iva: " << n2;
  cin.get();
  getchar();
        
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if i erase one of the two functions a the end (the cin.get() or the getchar()) it would just continue after the first "cin>>" statment ignoring the other function [sic]

It is very difficult to understand what you're trying to say, but this part leads me to believe you're asking why only one of those two functions isn't enough to **not** stop your program (ie end the `main` function).

That is because the `cin >> n1;` instruction reads just enough of your stdin stream to get the number, but it doesn't also "eat" the new line. So your `cin.get()` reads the new line that the other line didn't read, and `getchar()` then blocks your program until you press something else.

Comment: thanks a lot. So in resume, mi program stops it self in the first cin>>, then the cin.get() make it read the other lines and the getchar() make it stop. Souns good to me, i think I'm going to read more documentation about this lenguage before go beyond this point. Thanks a lot again for your time kind stranger.